# Detect if a Bing Map AJAX point is contained in a Polygon

Tags: javascript, bing-maps

Few days ago, I made a C# function, to detect if a point in inside of a polygon. After some drawbacks, I finally made the function. But after using for first time, I found that approach was very slower. Call a C# code behind function, from javascript, is very troublesome, since javascript continues the execution of the code, and don't wait for the result of the C# code.

Below, I posted the solution for this.

Comment: It's really unclear what you're asking. Can you maybe drop the unnecessary ?

Comment: @edi9999 I don't think there is a question.. this post should get removed.

Comment: This is not a question, just the OP sharing a piece of code

Comment: @edi9999 My intention is only share the code, to help others. This is not a question   :)

Comment: You should than rather ask a question and answer it yourself. Just putting your code in a question will probably not help anyone. Can you do that ?

Comment: @edi9999 done. Thanks for your advice. I'm relatively new to SO.

Comment: Great. Much better now

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I was forced to construct a new function, this time in plain javascript. After browsing a while, I found a couple of examples (using Google maps functions) and another in a Microsoft site (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc451895.aspx), but the function contained in the MS site always return false. Then, using as reference a code posted here in Stackoverflow, now I have a efficient javascript function, adapted to Bing maps AJAX v7. I hope can be useful for others. Don't forget to mark as useful!

```
loc = pushPin.getLocation();

var isInside = false;
var j = 0;
var x = loc.longitude;
var y = loc.latitude;
var paths = polygon.getLocations();

for (var i = 0; i < paths.length ; i++) {
    j++;
    if (j == paths.length) { j = 0; }
    if (((paths[i].latitude < y) && (paths[j].latitude >= y))
    || ((paths[j].latitude < y) && (paths[i].latitude >= y))) {
        if (paths[i].longitude + (y - paths[i].latitude)
        / (paths[j].latitude - paths[i].latitude)
        * (paths[j].longitude - paths[i].longitude) < x) {
            isInside = !isInside
        }
    }
}

if (isInside == true) { pushPin.setOptions({ visible: true }); };
```